# Comparing 2 columns with different rows in different csv files, and output status to another csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 2 csv files as shown below. They contain different numbers of rows and the columns are not aligned/sorted along a common index. I need to compare the column `fname` on both files, and if they are same, have to check if `place` is also the same or not, and output status `true` or `false` to another `file3.csv` with columns `fname, place, status`.

`file1.csv`:

```
fname.   age.  place 

Andy     16    a
kate.    15.   k
brian.   17.   b
```

`file2.csv`:

```
fname.   age.  place

brian.  17.   c
kate.   15.   k
andy.   16.   a
laura.  18.   l
```

output `file3.csv` should be like:

```
Andy.   a.   true
Kate.   k.   true
brian.  b.   false
```

I have seen quite number of queries similar to this, but they either have the same number of rows, or they are sorted and aligned along a common index.

I have tried using pandas, but that did not work, as the rows are different.

Comment: Please clarify the logic used to create the third file.  For example, if file1.fname.lower() ==  file2.fname.lower() use the file1fname value.  What determines if file3 contains a true vice fale condition?  What determines if file3 doesn't contain an entry for a fname value?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that will work using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

### Read the files into panda dataframes

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv)
```

### Create a common key for each dataframe

```
df1['lk'] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['fname'].lower(), axis= 1)  
df2['rk'] = df2.apply(lambda row: row['fname'].lower(), axis= 1)
```

### Merge the frames into a third df, and add flag column

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='lk', right_on='rk')
df3['flag'] = df3.apply(lambda row: row['place_x'] == row['place_y'], axis = 1)
```

### Rename the fname_x and place_X columns

```
df3.rename(columns={'fname_x':'fname', 'place_x':'place'}, inplace=True)
```

### Create the output csv file

```
df3[['fname', 'place', 'flag']].to_csv('file3', index=False)
```

Comment: This worked well, but I see repeated values in the output file

Comment: Also what if I want both true/false status in output file? instead of only matched rows with true

Comment: What do you mean by true/false?  The approach I provided produces True when the place data in df1 matches the place data in df2, else it produces False

Comment: The only issue I see is that some of your data contains a . at the end, and I assumed thiis was a typo on your part, if that is the case then modify the 'lk' and 'rk' creation by changing the ```row['fname'].lower()``` to ```row['fname'].lower()[:-1]```.